# rspec root route no index method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, bdd, rspec-rails

I have a simple controller:

```
class MonitorController < ApplicationController

    def pinger
        render text: 'pong'
    end


end
```

with routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    constraints subdomain: 'api' do
      scope module: 'api' do
        namespace :v1 do

        end
      end
    end
    # ********************************************************************************************
    root to: 'monitor#pinger'

end
```

and my controller test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MonitorController do

    context "#pinger" do
    it "Responds Successfully." do
            get "/"
            response.status.should be(200)
        end

        it "Should contain 'pong' in the response body." do
            get "/"
            response.body.should == "pong"
        end
  end

end
```

No matter what I do I can not seem to get the root route.

Error:

```
Failures:

  1) MonitorController#pinger Should contain 'pong' in the response body.
     Failure/Error: get "/"
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"monitor"}
     # ./spec/controllers/monitor_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) MonitorController#pinger Responds Successfully.
     Failure/Error: get "/"
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"monitor"}
     # ./spec/controllers/monitor_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.13662 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why these are failing?

Comment: I'm still learning `rspec`, but couldn't you use the path helper instead of `/` - `root_path` ?

Comment: unfortunately @RichPeck that did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rspec spec, try using:

```
get :pinger
```